# The right way to extend OptionSet with a constrained RawValue

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have an `OptionSet` for which I wanted to be able to perform bitwise operations (the operations in the `BitwiseOperation` protocol). I wrote an extension to my type, then realized I should make it reusable code. It took a while to figure out a way, and what I did was make a protocol that inherits from both protocols and adds a constraint on the associated type, then a protocol extension providing default implementations.

It works, but my question is this: Is this the best way to accomplish this?

```
protocol BitwiseOptionSet : BitwiseOperations, OptionSet {
    associatedtype RawValue : BitwiseOperations, ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral
}
extension BitwiseOptionSet {
    static var allZeros : Self {
        return Self(rawValue: 0)
    }
    prefix static func ~(x: Self) -> Self {
        return Self(rawValue: ~x.rawValue)
    }
    static func ^(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        return Self(rawValue: lhs.rawValue ^ rhs.rawValue)
    }
    static func &(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        return Self(rawValue: lhs.rawValue & rhs.rawValue)
    }
    static func |(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        return Self(rawValue: lhs.rawValue | rhs.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `OptionSet` with a constraint on its `RawValue`:

```
extension OptionSet where RawValue: BitwiseOperations {
    static var allZeros : Self {
        return Self(rawValue: .allZeros)
    }
    prefix static func ~(x: Self) -> Self {
        return Self(rawValue: ~x.rawValue)
    }
    static func ^(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        return Self(rawValue: lhs.rawValue ^ rhs.rawValue)
    }
    static func &(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        return Self(rawValue: lhs.rawValue & rhs.rawValue)
    }
    static func |(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        return Self(rawValue: lhs.rawValue | rhs.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Note that requiring a conformance to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` 
can be avoided by using `Self(rawValue: .allZeros)` instead of
`Self(rawValue: 0)`.

Example:

```
struct MyOptionSet: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: UInt16
    init(rawValue: UInt16) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }
}

let a = MyOptionSet(rawValue: 3)
let b = MyOptionSet(rawValue: 5)
let c = a & b
print(c.rawValue) // 1
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do, and I think I was close. I think I had the constraint formatted improperly.

Comment: Thanks for the note about `.allZeros` to avoid the additional constraint.